# Airplay TV audio to WiFi speakers

Tags: audio, streaming, input-device

I have been seriously searching and searching for a way to get my TV audio to my Sonos speakers via Airplay. I definitely know that the Raspberry Pi can Airplay play, but what I don’t know is which one has the ability to take in audio from my TV. My TV has an optical out and component out.